# no emulator is currently running in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I have android studio bumblee 2021 version. during run an app on android emulator the emulator show some issues.
[no emulators are currently running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDnTI.png)

[installed emulator in SDK manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC3B2.png)

How to fix this issues?

Comment: Did you get around to fixing this? I'm facing the exact same problem.

Comment: We're suddenly having this issue after unsuspending the machine that runs the emulator, and no amount of nuking seems to fix it.